# Python Input Function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering if somebody could tell me what is wrong with this code, when I run the code it shows nothing but if I take out the "elif" it does work.\

```
first=input("What is your first name? ");
middle=input("What is your middle name? ");
last=input("What is your last name? ");
test = [first, middle, last];
print ("");
print ("Firstname: " + test[0]);
print ("Middlename: " + test[1]);
print ("Lastname: " + test[2]);
print ("");
correct=input("This is the information you input, correct? ");
if (correct == "Yes" or "yes"):
    print ("Good!")
elif (correct == "no" or "No"):
    print ("Sorry about that there must be some error!");
```

Comment: People have pointed out that the tests in your `if` and `else` are probably not what you want, but are you sure it really prints nothing??

Comment: To amplify @gnibbler, `False or "yes"` → `True` and `True or "yes"` → `True` therefore `print("Good!")` should always execute regardless of the value of `correct`.

Answer (score 6):

Here's the problem:

```
if (correct == "Yes" or "yes"):
    # ...
elif (correct == "no" or "No"):
    # ...
```

It should be:

```
if correct in ("Yes", "yes"):
    # ...
elif correct in ("No", "no"):
    # ...
```

Notice that the right way to make a comparison involving several conditions is like this:

```
correct == "Yes" or correct == "yes"
```

But usually it gets written like this, which is shorter:

```
correct in ("Yes", "yes")
```

Comment: I input that and it still doesn't have an output of anything.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `in` keyword:

```
if correct in ("Yes", "yes"):
    print ("Good!")
elif correct in ("no", "No"):
    print ("Sorry about that there must be some error!")
```

or convert the entire input to the same case:

```
# I use the lower method of a string here to make the input all lowercase
correct=input("This is the information you input, correct? ").lower()
if correct == "yes":
    print ("Good!")
elif correct == "no":
    print ("Sorry about that there must be some error!")
```

Personally, I think the `lower` solution is the cleanest and best.  Note however that it will make your script accept inputs such as "YeS", "yEs", etc.  If this is a problem, go with the first solution.

Answer (score 1):

You'e checking `correct` incorrectly

```
if (correct == "Yes" or "yes"):
```

means `(correct == "Yes") or ("yes")`, and non-empty string evaluates to `True` in python, so first condition will always be `True`.If you want to check multiple strings, you can do:

```
if (correct in ("Yes", "yes")):
```

But this one doesn't takes `'yEs'` or `'yES'` into account. If you want case-insensitive comparison, then I think `correct.lower() == "yes"` would be preferred method.